# Generating elements based on underlying tuple types during run-time

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

How can I deduce the type or pair elements during compile-time? I need it to make a correct instantion accordingly to argument type (e.g. for Integer_random_generator those may be long, int, unsigned int etc., for real_random_generator double, float and other floating-points). I need to make generators with certain bounds as you can see in the commented out lines 63-77.

```
#ifndef OPTIMALIZATION_HPP
#define OPTIMALIZATION_HPP

    #include<utility>
    #include<random>
    #include<experimental/random>
    #include<functional>
    #include<experimental/functional>
    #include<experimental/tuple>
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<type_traits>
    #include<iostream>

    #include"tuple_for_each.hpp"

    //ZNAJDZ/ZROB INDEKSOWANY DOSTEP DO TUPLI W CZASIE RUN-TIME'U
    namespace numerics{
        template<
            std::size_t population_size, std::size_t generations,
            typename Func,
            typename Compare, //GREATER, LESS, TYPE RETURNED BY FUNCTION
            typename Generator=std::default_random_engine,
            template<typename>
                typename RealDistribution=std::uniform_real_distribution,
            template<typename>
                typename IntegerDistribution=std::uniform_int_distribution,
            typename ...Ts
        >
        auto optimize(
                const Func& function, const Compare& comp,
                const std::pair<Ts,Ts>&... range
        ){

            std::size_t range_argument_count=sizeof...(range);
            static_assert(range_argument_count>2,
                    "Function needs at least two range arguments"
            );

            //RANDOM NUMBER GENERATORS
            auto real_random_generator=[&](const std::pair<auto,auto> range){
                std::cout << "DOUBLE" << std::endl;
                return std::bind(
                        RealDistribution<long double>(range.first,range.second),
                        //RealDistribution<decltype(range.first)>(range.first,range.second);
                        //HOW TO DEDUCE TYPE OF DISTRIBUTION FROM PAIR DURING COMPILE-TIME???
                        Generator()
                );
            };

            auto integer_random_generator=[&](const std::pair<auto,auto>& range){
            std::cout << "INTEGER" << std::endl;
                return std::bind(
                        IntegerDistribution<long long>(range.first,range.second),
                        //IntegerDistribution<decltype(range.first)>(range.first,range.second);
                        //HOW TO DEDUCE TYPE OF DISTRIBUTION FROM PAIR DURING COMPILE-TIME???
                        Generator()
                );
            };
            std::cout << integer_random_generator(std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(range...)))() << std::endl;
            std::cout << real_random_generator(std::get<1>(std::make_tuple(range...)))()<<std::endl;
            std::cout << integer_random_generator(std::get<2>(std::make_tuple(range...)))()<<std::endl;

            //GENERATORS DEPENDING ON TYPE, USED THROUGH WHOLE PROGRAM
            /*std::tuple<> generators;
            numerics::for_each(std::make_tuple(range...), [&](std::pair<auto,auto>& x){ //FOR_EACH SPRAWDZENIA
                    try{
                        generators=std::tuple_cat(
                                generators,
                                std::make_tuple(integer_random_generator(x.first)));
                    }
                    catch(...){
                        generators=std::tuple_cat(
                                generators,
                                std::make_tuple(real_random_generator(x.first)));
                    }
                }
            );*/
            return "pls work";
        }
    }
    #endif
```

Test cases:

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>
#include"optimize.hpp"

class Function{
    public:
        Function()=default;
        double operator()(int x, double y, long z)const{
            return (std::exp(x+1.25)*std::pow(y,z))/std::exp((x*y)/z);
        }
};

int main(){
    Function f{};
    auto comp=std::less<double>();
    auto x=numerics::optimize<100, 200>(
            f, comp,
            std::make_pair(-21, 37),
            std::make_pair(14.88, 88.41),
            std::make_pair(-13, 37)
    );
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to deduce from what. Can you elaborate on what your problem is? Preferably in a more minimal example.

Comment: What is the problem with your commented-out code `IntegerDistribution<decltype(range.first)>(range.first,range.second);`? Does it give a compile error? If so, what?

Comment: Take a look at [mcve] for some advise on how to simplify your problem to make it easier for others to understand.

Comment: @Smeeheey This line was okay, sorry, I'm still new to posting on StackOverflow. Answer below is what I was looking for.

Comment: @MostLovelyRollOnThePlanet - unrelated to your question but... remember to define `constexpr` the `range_argument_count`; if it's a simple variable, you can't use it in the following `static_assert()`

Comment: @max66 I did, removed it by an accident when posting this code as I had to clean it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a helper function to determine whether to make a real or an integer generator.  In this case it will be based off the type of the first parameter in the range.  I will leave it to you to determine how to also check the second parameter.  (I haven't tested this code, but I am confident that the idea works).

```
template <class Range>
auto get_distribution(Range range, std::true_type)
{
    return real_random_generator(range);
}

template <class Range>
auto get_distribution(Range range, std::false_type)
{
    return integer_random_generator(range);
}
```

Simply use the pack expansion syntax to call your helper function on every range

```
auto generators = std::make_tuple(get_distribution(ranges, 
                      std::is_floating_point<decltype(ranges.first)>{})...);
```

The `std::is_floating_point` is what determines which overload gets called for each range.

If you like tricky, but more concise, code you could try this out:

```
auto fs = std::make_tuple(integer_random_generator, real_random_generator);
auto generator = std::make_tuple(std::get<std::is_floating_point<decltype(ranges.first)>::value>(fs)(ranges)...);
```

Construct a tuple of your generator-generating lambdas (this wouldn't work  if they weren't objects) and use the condition as an index into the tuple and immediately call it.  I don't advocate using this, but I thought I would share it nonetheless.

Comment: The tricky one is really a great idea, but you need to give ranges instead of ranges.first in the second line, second argument, otherwise perfect, thanks!

Comment: @MostLovelyRollOnThePlanet I think it's also a bug in the original post that I just copied over.  Thanks for pointing it out.